# Query on overloading << operator in C++

Tags: c++

Below is my program, which gives, following errors

```
c:\mystuff>cl dummy.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.30319.01 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

dummy.cpp
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE\xlocale(323) : wa
rning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. S
pecify /EHsc

dummy.cpp(20) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '&'

dummy.cpp(20) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ doe
s not support default-int

dummy.cpp(20) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ostream'

dummy.cpp(20) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ doe
s not support default-int

dummy.cpp(20) : error C2805: binary 'operator <<' has too few parameters

dummy.cpp(20) : error C2333: 'Complex::operator <<' : error in function declarat
ion; skipping function body

dummy.cpp(32) : error C2065: 'cout' : undeclared identifier






#include<iostream> 
class Complex{
private:
    double real;
    double imag;

public:
    Complex(double real, double imag){
        this->real = real;
        this->imag = imag;
    }

    Complex operator+ (const Complex& Operand){
        double real = this->real + Operand.real;
        double imag = this->imag + Operand.imag;
        return Complex(real,imag);
    }

    ostream &operator<< (ostream  &o, Complex Operand){//line 20
        o  << Operand.real;
        o  << Operand.imag;
        return o;
    }
};

int main(){
    Complex c1(1,2);
    Complex c2(3,4);

    Complex c3 = c1 + c2;

    cout << c3;


}
```

My question:

1)

At line 32 cout is visible by including extern object `cout` from `iostream`, so, What is the reason for error at line 32 `cout << c3`?

2)

Please help me understand, the reason for error at line #20. `operator<<` method is just copied from the book. In addition, I would like to understand why we should pass `ostream` reference as first formal parameter in `operator<<` method. Because, In `operator+` method, i used only one operand as formal parameter by using `this` for accessing first operand object. Can't i do the same for `operator<<` method by using `this`?

Comment: See [operator overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading). The way you've overloaded it, it needs to be called on an instance of `Complex`.

Comment: `ostream` should be `std::ostream` on line 20 and following. Line 32, `cout` should be `std::cout`.

Comment: You should have added `using namespace std;` to use cout and friends without std:: prefix.

Comment: Also the definition of `operator<<` is wrong. It must be a non-member function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared the operator as a member function. This means it has to operate on an instance of `Complex` on the LHS and has too many parameters. What you need is to make it a non-member. One way of achieving this, and giving the operator access to the non-public members of `Complex`, is to declare it as a `friend` inside the `Complex` class definition:

```
friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream & o, const Complex& Operand){
    o  << Operand.real;
    o  << Operand.imag;
    return o;
}
```

Besides that, `ostream` lives in the `std` namespace, so refer to is as `std::ostream` (likewise for `cout` elsewhere in your code.)

Note that here I also pass `Operand` by `const` reference, since you don't need a copy.

You have exactly the same problem with `Complex operator+ (const Complex& Operand)`.

Comment: you answered 2nd question

Comment: @Sham I think I answered both. But you should only be asking one question anyway.

Comment: sorry juan you are right. Are we adhering to asignature of operator<< method saying it should take ostream object as first parameter, why are we not using 'this' to access ostream object, as we are calling << on ostream object cout?

Comment: @Sham The operator should not be a member in this case (that is the main point of my answer), so there is no `this` involved.

Comment: operator << should not be a member in the sense, it is not even a member of ostream class? As you say 'std::cout << c3' so i was assuming we are calling << on cout object. am i wrong here? So friend specifier method is not a member of any class?

Comment: @Sham that is correct. `std::cout` is an `std::ostream`.

Comment: one last question, 'cout << c3;' does not imply an intuition that one need  to write an operator << method with ostream as first formal parameter, do u think the same? Is this blind c++ style that compiler is expecting?

Comment: @Sham That is fine. `operator symbol (LHS, RHS)` is used as `LHS symbol RHS`. Here, `symbol` is `<<`.

Comment: if you say, operator symbol(lhs, rhs), then are we actually overloading <<? No i dont think so?

Comment: sorry moderator, can we dicuss this on chat?

Comment: @Sham Yes, you're overloading `ostream& operator<<(ostream&, Complex)`, regardless of what you think :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify name space where names cout and ostream are defined. For example

```
std::ostream &operator<< (std::ostream  &o, Complex Operand){//line 20
    o  << Operand.real;
    o  << Operand.imag;
    return o;
}

std::cout << c3;
```

Or you could include directive

```
using namespace std;
```

after the included header. Or you could use using declarations

```
using std::ostream;
using std::cout;
```

The first approach when qualified names are used is preferable.

Also `operator <<` must be defined as a friend function

```
friend std::ostream &operator<< (std::ostream  &o, const Complex &Operand){//line 20
    o  << Operand.real;
    o  << Operand.imag;
    return o;
}
```

So the class could be defined as

```
class Complex{
private:
    double real;
    double imag;

public:
    Complex(double real, double imag){
        this->real = real;
        this->imag = imag;
    }

    Complex operator+ (const Complex& Operand) const {
        double real = this->real + Operand.real;
        double imag = this->imag + Operand.imag;
        return Complex(real,imag);
    }

    friend std::ostream &operator<< (std::ostream  &o, const Complex &Operand){//line 20
        o  << Operand.real;
        o  << Operand.imag;
        return o;
    }
};
```

Comment: ok vlad cout is in the scope of std, but what is the idea of compiler author to include cout in std scope?

Comment: @Sham  All standard names with very rare exceptions are declared in namespace std thet there will not be collisions with user defined names.

Comment: so i can use my flavour of cout which can be different from std::cout

Comment: @Sham Yes you can. For example you could define int cout;

Answer (score -1):

To correctly overload the << operator, you must write a function outside the class

```
ostream &operator<< (ostream &o, Complex Operand){
    o  << Operand.real;
    o  << Operand.imag;
    return o;
}
```

and then declare it as friend inside the class

```
friend ostream &operator<< (ostream &, Complex);
```

Also, i believe that you wanted to output something like this:

```
o << Operand.real << " + " << Operand.imag << "i";
```

Also, try using

```
using namespace std;
```

after the include lines as ostream and many other features of c++ are within the std namespace.